# Apple Game Center what exactly can you re-skin?

Tags: game-center

I read elsewhere on here that it's possible to re-skin the Apple Game Center? Few questions about that..

1) What exactly can you re-skin? all of it? or just some parts?

2) Is it wise to re-skin the GUI of game center or is it more trouble than it's worth?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skin Leaderboards - achievements - turnbased games

You can't skin: Login screen - `GKMatchMakerView` or `GKTurnBasedMatchMakerView` (actually you can if you're accepting not to use invitation features)